# How to configure npm package so that global install puts it on the path?

Tags: node.js, npm, path, stream, global

I've got a node module that I'm trying to publish as a global NPM package, so that when you install with -g, it puts a couple commands in the path automatically.

In this case my module is called [ncrypt-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncrypt-stream) and it has two commands -- node encrypt.js and node descrypt.js -- I want to be able to run these commands by simply typing encrypt or decrypt from anywhere in the file system.

I know this package is probably reinventing the wheel: it is a learning exercise more than anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `bin` option in your `package.json` to specify binaries.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

> { "bin" : { "myapp" : "./cli.js" } }

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for... Thanks